# Dropping values from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, unique

I have a list of tuples which I would like to only return the second column of data from and only unique values

```
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
```

Desired output:

```
['Andrew@gmail.com','Jim@gmail.com','Sarah@gmail.com']
```

My idea would be to iterate through the list and append the item from the second column into a new list then use the following code. Before I go down that path too far I know there is a better way to do this.

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(mytuple_new)
unique_mytuple_new = [k for k, v in cnt.iteritems() if v > 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` function :

```
>>> set(zip(*mytuple)[1])
set(['Sarah@gmail.com', 'Jim@gmail.com', 'Andrew@gmail.com'])
```

Or as a less performance way you can use `map` and `operator.itemgetter` and use `set` to get the unique tuple :

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> tuple(set(map(lambda x:itemgetter(1)(x),mytuple)))
('Sarah@gmail.com', 'Jim@gmail.com', 'Andrew@gmail.com')
```

## a benchmarking on some answers :

my answer :

```
s = """\
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
set(zip(*mytuple)[1])
"""
print timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.0740020275116
```

---

icodez answer :

```
s = """\
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
seen = set()
[x[1] for x in mytuple if x[1] not in seen and not seen.add(x[1])]
"""
print timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.0938332080841
```

---

Hasan's answer :

```
s = """\
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
set([k[1] for k in mytuple])
"""
print timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.0699651241302
```

---

Adem's answer :

```
s = """
from itertools import izip
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
set(map(lambda x: x[1], mytuple))
"""
print timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.237300872803 !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
>>> unique_mytuple_new = set([k[1] for k in mytuple])
>>> unique_mytuple_new
set(['Sarah@gmail.com', 'Jim@gmail.com', 'Andrew@gmail.com'])
```

Comment: @user3885927 sorry dude. a wrongly rejected your edit!!

Answer (score 1):

```
unique_emails = set(item[1] for item in mytuple)
```

The list comprehension will help you generate a list containing only the second column data, and converting that list to `set()` removes duplicated values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and a set to keep track of seen values:

```
>>> mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x[1] for x in mytuple if x[1] not in seen and not seen.add(x[1])]
['Andrew@gmail.com', 'Jim@gmail.com', 'Sarah@gmail.com']
>>>
```

The most important part of this solution is that order is preserved like in your example.  Doing just `set(x[1] for x in mytuple)` or something similar will get you the unique items, but their order will be lost.

Also, the `if x[1] not in seen and not seen.add(x[1])` may seem a little strange, but it is actually a neat trick that allows you to add items to the set inside the list comprehension (otherwise, we would need to use a for-loop).

Because `and` performs short-circuit evaluation in Python, `not seen.add(x[1])` will only be evaluated if `x[1] not in seen` returns `True`.  So, the condition sees if `x[1]` is in the set and adds it if not.

The `not` operator is placed before `seen.add(x[1])` so that the condition evaluates to `True` if `x[1]` needed to be added to the set (`set.add` returns `None`, which is treated as `False`.  `not False` is `True`).

Answer (score 0):

How about the obvious and simple loop? There is no need to create a list and then convert to set, just don't add dupliates.

```
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
result = []
for item in mytuple:
    if item[1] not in result:
        result.append(item[1]) 
print result
```

**Output:**

```
['Andrew@gmail.com', 'Jim@gmail.com', 'Sarah@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the order of the items important? A lot of the proposed answers use `set` to unique-ify the list. That's good, proper, and performant if the order is unimportant. If order does matter, you can used an `OrderedDict` to perform set-like unique-ification while preserving order.

```
# test data
mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]

from collections import OrderedDict
emails = list(OrderedDict((t[1], 1) for t in mytuple).keys())
print emails
```

Yielding:

```
['Andrew@gmail.com', 'Jim@gmail.com', 'Sarah@gmail.com']
```

**Update**

Based on iCodez's suggestion, restating answer to:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
emails = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(t[1] for t in mytuple).keys())
```

Comment: You can actually just do: `emails = OrderedDict.fromkeys(x[1] for x in mytuple).keys()`.

Comment: Fair point. In Python 2, that works great, and I guess that's the version we're targeting. I try to write code that will work seamlessly in Python 3, though. And in py3, the `keys` method returns a view object. You can iterate over it and use it somewhat as you would a `list`...but it's not a true `list`.

Comment: So then do `emails = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x[1] for x in mytuple))`.  That works in both versions.  I was just giving a suggestion though.  Your current code works fine too.

Comment: Yep. Answer is updated with that cleaner formulation. Thanks!